# Received fatal alert:bad_certificate in java web service

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, certificate, keystore

i'm trying to connect to EJBCA server with my client run on jboss. If my client is a standalone java application it runs correctly, but when the client is a Rest web service i have this error:

```
    WARN  [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8080-1) Interceptor for {http://ws.protocol.core.ejbca.org/}EjbcaWSService#{http://ws.protocol.core.ejbca.org/}certificateRequest has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64) [cxf-api-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272) [cxf-api-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:570) [cxf-api-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:479) [cxf-api-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382) [cxf-api-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335) [cxf-api-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96) [cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.6.8.jar:2.6.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.6.8.jar:2.6.8]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy185.certificateRequest(Unknown Source)
    at it.prisma.businesslayer.bizlib.certificationauthority.CaHelper.addCertificate(CaHelper.java:336) [classes:]
    at it.prisma.businesslayer.bizws.certificationauthority.TestRestWS.ReleaseCertificate(TestRestWS.java:54) [classes:]
    at it.prisma.businesslayer.bizws.certificationauthority.TestRestWS$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.ReleaseCertificate(TestRestWS$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:288) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:242) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:229) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.7.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.exception.CatchExceptionFilter.doFilter(CatchExceptionFilter.java:65) [solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.ServletEventBridgeFilter.doFilter(ServletEventBridgeFilter.java:74) [solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:397) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSLHandshakeException invoking https://xxxxx:8443/ejbca/ejbcaws/ejbcaws: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1474) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.6.8.jar:2.6.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1459) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.6.8.jar:2.6.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56) [cxf-api-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:660) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.6.8.jar:2.6.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62) [cxf-api-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    ... 49 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1403) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.6.8.jar:2.6.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1347) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.6.8.jar:2.6.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47) [cxf-api-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69) [cxf-api-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1431) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.6.8.jar:2.6.8]
    ... 52 more
```

the java code is the same of standalone application, so as keystore and truststore.
I use jBoss 7.1.1.Final and maven.
Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is the conflict between many version of cxf present in maven pom